# How much harmful radiation do gaming PCs/desktop Pcs emit?

Tags: desktop, desktop-computer

I have a gaming PC and the IO shield is missing a few tabs--I heard that these tabs are used to prevent electromagnetic interference. Can I get harmful radiation from not having some of the tabs? The PC sits in a metal case a foot or two away from me, and it has a WiFi adapter.

Comment: There is no issue. No harmful emissions are produced by PCs, even those with WiFi adapters.

Comment: I'm not sure why this is attracting "opinion-based" close votes. It's really not a matter of opinion at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tabs are part of what effectively makes up a [Faraday cage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_cage), to prevent the **computer** suffering from electromagnetic interference.

Computers do not emit 'harmful radiation' in any meaningful sense.

Scare tactics & "fear, uncertainty & doubt" [FUD] add apparent 'truths' with no real scientific basis whatsoever.

Links…

1. Complete & utter bul…t scare tactics to persuade you to buy their "radiation shield".
   https://www.vesttech.com/6-reasons-you-should-never-place-your-laptop-on-your-lap/
2. Rational general answers to common fears.
   [Health Physics Society - Computer/VDT Screens](https://hps.org/publicinformation/ate/faqs/computervdtscreen.html)